# Functionality like $(document).ready( with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I wrote a small code with Laravel, Vue and JQuery, which works fine. Now I want to **remove JQuery** and run all with Vue and Axios.

Here's my template:

```
 <ul id="product_list" class="vue-list-wrapper list-wrapper" data-rest="{{ route('rest_get_products', ["id"=>$product_type_id]) }}" data-pagination="0">
    <li v-for="item in items">
        <div class="item-name item-section">@{{ item.name }}</div>
        ...bla bla...
    </li>
</ul>
```

Following code actually works and I can render what I get from AJAX. I know how to apply Axios, no problem.

The point I'm confused about: **How can I ensure `$(document).ready(` functionality with Vue**?

```
(function(){
"use strict";

function init_vue_list(){

    var vue_list_handler = new Vue({
        el: '.vue-list-wrapper',
        data: {
            items: []
        },
        mounted: function (event) {
            var self = this;
            var ajax_url = this.$el.getAttribute('data-rest');

            $.ajax({ // No problem to convert this to Axios.
                url: ajax_url,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    self.items = data;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        },
        methods:{
            open_production:function(event){
                
            }
        }
    });

}

$(document).ready( // I'm confused how I can replace this with Vue.
    function(){
        if($('.vue-list-wrapper').length > 0) {
            init_vue_list();
        }
    }
);

})(document, $);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The recommended way by vue to do this is using **mounted()**.

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Code that will run only after the
    // entire view has been rendered
  })
}
```

Check: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: I already have mounted on my code, so most probably calling document ready is very unnecessary here..

Comment: Additionally, in using `this.$nextTick` you ensure that the entire view has been rendered as well. Have a go at it!

Answer (score 4):

Similar approach, but without JQuery and just using Javascript:

```js
mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        // INSERT CODE HERE
    });
}
```

---

## ES6 Update

Here's the ES6 version of the script using the arrow function:

```
mounted() {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // INSERT CODE HERE
  });
}
```

Comment: Great! This code is very useful! I would just add an `if` to the top just to check if the content isn't already loaded. This would avoid not loading anything. Something like: `if (document.readyState === "loading") {  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doSomething) } else { doSomething() }`

Comment: This does not seem to work with Vue3/Laravel and composition API? it never triggers..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside mounted, assuming that you are using JQuery:

```
mounted() {
    $(function() {
        // Your code goes here...
    })
 }
```